# Button that will prompt for a file name before saving to PDF

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I have the following against a button to export a report to pdf but I would like Access to prompt the user to type in the file name before saving to the location.

I managed to get it to save to a certain file path - but the file name needs to be changed before it saves. I currently have the file name set to "Rename this Client invoice.pdf".

```vb
Private Sub btnSaveInv_Click()
 
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptINVOICE", _
acFormatPDF, "C:\Users\soosi\OneDrive - VTA Services\VTA Services\ACCOUNTS\Rename this CLIENT Invoice.pdf"
 
End Sub
```

Ideally I want this to pick up the client name that is a field on the form that this button sits, but I can't get that to work so this was the next best thing.

Comment: Use either an `InputBox` to manually type the full path, or even better use a save as dialog to select the path and type the file name only. You can find examples for both in SO.

Comment: Hi - my attempt didn't fail as such as it is saving the invoice with the "Rename this client invoice" file name in the location specified.  
What I am looking for is either of the following:  

1) A piece of code to add what i have already that prompts the user for the file name - which would be the invoice number and the client name.

or something a bit smarter that will grab the client name/invoice number information on the current form and use that as the file name and save it in the location after pressing the btn.    (I hope this makes sense!)

Comment: :) that was why i needed some help - I wasn't sure how to add this to my code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Access user, so the part to get the client name as the default filename might need tweaking, but you can try this:

```vb
Private Sub btnSaveInv_Click()
    Const FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Users\soosi\OneDrive - VTA Services\VTA Services\ACCOUNTS\"
    Dim fName As String
    
    fName = Me.clientName.Value & " " & Me.invoiceNumber.Value '<< change as needed...
    
    fName = InputBox("Enter the filename (do not include the '.pdf')", "Enter File Name", fName)
    
    If Len(fName) > 0 Then
        If Not fName Like "*.pdf" Then fName = fName & ".pdf"
        fName = FOLDER_PATH & fName               'prepend the path
        If Dir(fName, vbNormal) <> "" Then        'check if file already exists
            If MsgBox("This file already exists - overwrite?", _
                      vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
        End If
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptINVOICE", acFormatPDF, fName
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you I will give this a go - How would I also grab the invoice number - I would like the client name and the invoice number to form the file name when it saves?

Comment: I'm not sure how you could grab the invoice number - grab from where exactly?

Comment: It is on the same form where the Client Name is

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: Hi, this all worked well until it came to save to the file path and I suspect it's because...

Comment: You'll need to check whether the client name or invoice number contain characters not allowed in a file name.